# JSON path does not match Expected: (a collection containing <["excpetedValue"]>) Actual: <[excpetedValue]>

Tags: java, json, cucumber, rest-assured

I have some JSON file with expected result saved in a json file
I create JSONobj from it:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(myJson);
```

Then I use my variables to get the right json (I have different users, which are here shown as variables)

```
JSONObject jsonObjData = jsonObject.getJSONObject(variable1).getJSONObject(variable2);
```

Then I have some real response which I am trying to compare (just part of) with my expected json (array)

My code so far:

```
ValidatableResponse respBody = response.then();
JSONArray expectedListArr = jsonObjData .getJSONArray(dtEntry);
respBody.body("myPath", hasItems(expectedListArr));
}
```

I use cucumber so it looks like this:

```
And Values for key "myPath" equals the following
  | myVariable2 |
```

And step

```
@Then("Values for key {string} equals the following")
    public void valuesForListContains(String pathKey, DataTable dt) {
        ValidatableResponse respBody = response.then();
        if (dt.values().stream().anyMatch(a->a.contains("myVariables "))) {
            String dtEntry = dt.toString().replaceAll("\\|","").trim();
            JSONArray expectedListArr = jsonObjData.getJSONArray(dtEntry);
            respBody.body("myPath", hasItems(expectedListArr));
        }
```

I don't know if I'm going round and round, butthe above shows me:

**1 expectation failed.
JSON path deliveryCountries doesn't match.
Expected: (a collection containing <["excpetedValue"]>)
Actual: <[excpetedValue]>**

my json:

```
{
"myVariable4": [
        {
          "key1": val,
          etc.
        }
      ],
      "myVariable2": [
        "expectedValue"
      ],
      "myVariable3": [
        "val1",
        "val2",
        "val3",
        "val4",
etc.
      ],}
```

Comment: I believe you're just comparing different types. Probably you expect to have a collection but you receive something that is not a collection, etc. Can you show your response? And the actual jsonpath you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but i dont understand your question!

if you have a JSON like this:

```
{
"myVariable4": [
        {
          "key1": val,
          etc.
        }
      ],
      "myVariable2": [
        "expectedValue"
      ],
      "myVariable3": [
        "val1",
        "val2",
        "val3",
        "val4",
etc.
      ],}
```

so first du must get the JSONArray:

```
JSONArray myvaribl4 = jsonObject.getJSONArray("myVariable4");
```

After that you can get the Object again with:

```
for(int i =0; i<myvaribl4.length; i++){
   JSONObject jobj = myvaribl4.getJSONObject(i);
}
```

if the array have ONLY one Object:

```
JSONObject jobj = myvaribl4.getJSONObject(0);
```

Then you get key1 value with:

```
String value = jobj.getString("key1");
```

I hope I understood your question correctly.

Comment: I need to compare two JSONarrays but I got the error like above. I don't need to extract single strings, because sometimes the array is more than 1 string.

Comment: doing fori you suggested i got: org.json.JSONException: JSONArray[0] is not a JSONObject.

Comment: Please post your Code, i dont know what you done.